# 'fscanf' alterando ponteiro para struct em C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Boa noite.

Eu estava escrevendo um programa para ler strings de um arquivo de texto, 
e colocar estas em uma lista simplesmente encadeada caso seu comprimento
fosse igual a 5.

O problema é que o programa começou a não funcionar do jeito que eu
esperava, e após alguns testes, descobri que um ponteiro que eu estava
usando passava a apontar do nada para outro endereço de memória, 
após algumas iterações e um comando 'fscanf'.

Coloquei no Pastebin o código de testes que escrevi:
https://pastebin.com/4VRrxqgJ

O arquivo "keys.txt" contém as seguintes strings:

m4mSx
fr4
mWKgC
7bbak
7
NP3Rw

Eu escrevi outro código que resolve sem problemas oque eu queria fazer, mas
eu gostaria de saber o porque de estar acontecendo este erro com este
código de teste, visto que pelo que sei não faz sentido isto estar ocorrendo.

Comment: Não esquecer que as strings em C são terminadas por '\0' de modo que para guardar "m4mSx" vais precisar de pelo menos 6 casas.

Comment: Testei seu programa e não houve mudança de endereço... O programa que você passou foi editado, não? Poderia providenciar o original? Não vejo nenhum problema além do que o @JJoao mencionou e o fato de você ter feito type-cast nos `malloc`s.